# Associate Boostrap Pagination with Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I used the below code to render pagination in my view. It is working fine. But I could not find any document to associate this pagination for the corresponding table. Right now all the rows in my table are loading. I am pretty sure somewhere I need to specify the table to associate the pagination.
Any Ideas?

```
var options = {
        currentPage: 1,
        totalPages: 1000,
        bootstrapMajorVersion: 3,

    }

    $('#myPager').bootstrapPaginator(options);
```

view

```
<ul class="pagination" id="myPager">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap pagination component has no logic to perform client-side pagination out of the box, you have to write it on your own.

If you use **bootstrap-paginator.js** you should perform an ajax request like this way:

```
var options = {
        currentPage: 3,
        totalPages: 10,
        onPageClicked: function(e,originalEvent,type,page){
            $('#table').html(htmlData);

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "GetTableDataUrl",
                data: { page: page }
            })
            .done(function( htmlData ) {
                $('#table').html(htmlData);
            });
        }
    }

$('#example').bootstrapPaginator(options);
```

Your MVC action should looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetTableDataUrl(int page)
    {
        // retrieve data for the wanted page
        return PartialView("");
    }
```

I suggest you to use this Nuget Package: ***PagedList.Mvc***
It contains a set of Html helpers that allow to perform pagination passing the wanted page number to the action as parameter and rendering the bootstrap component accordingly.

Please take a look to the official tutorial on [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this is not an answer.

Comment: I have used `bootstrap-paginator.js`